# trying to understand the concept of being unable to mutate strings/numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, mutators

In Javascript, you can reassign a variable like:

```
var x = 10;
x+=10;
console.log(x);
//prints 20 to the console
```

But if I take another example of a seemingly similar activity I get an unexpected result:

```
var originalVar = 1;

changeMyVar(originalVar);

function changeMyVar(myVar) {
  myVar += 1000;
  return myVar;
}

console.log(originalVar);
//prints 1 to the console
```

I see this as one in the same. I am passing my variable as an argument into a function. I'm reassigning the value within that function. And then I'm returning and printing that variable. Where is the mutation?

Comment: You need to learn how things are passed and referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives as function parameters are passed by value in javascript. Therefore `myVar` in `changeMyVar` function is not reference to `originalVar` but new variable with value of `originalVar`.

Answer (score 1):

**I hope it will solve your problem :**

**`According to your question`**

**Code :**

```
var originalVar = 1;

changeMyVar(originalVar);

function changeMyVar(myVar) {
  myVar += 1000;
  return myVar;
}

console.log(originalVar);
```

**Output :**

`1` // prints 1 to the console

**Explanation :**

If it was pure pass by reference, then everything would have changed. **`originalVar`** would be 1001.

In practical terms, this means that if you change the parameter itself (as with originalVar), that won't affect the item that was fed into the parameter. But if you change the INTERNALS of the parameter, that will propagate back up (as with objects properties).

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+=` reasssigns the variable. It does not reassign the number that the variable represents.

Let's say 'originalVar' is a box with one ball in it. Then calling `changeMyVar(originalVar)` calls the `changeMyVar` function with `myVar` equal to the value of `originalVar`, so `myVar` is a box with 1 ball in it. The line `myVar += 1000` adds 1000 balls to the myVar box. It does not change the concept of 1 ball into the concept of 1001 balls. So now `originalVar` still equals 1, but `myVar` equals 1001.